# Keycloak - write to and read custom entries from Infinispan

Tags: keycloak, infinispan

Is there a way to write to and read custom entries from Infinispan in a custom Keycloak SPI?

So, for an example, if you’d want to track a number of failed login attempts for a given user, could you store a simple count-by-username map within Infinispan?

I’d like to achieve this with Infinispan in order to cache the value across the whole Keycloak cluster, not a single node.

Is this possible to do with Infinispan and Keycloak?

Comment: _track a number of failed login attempts for a given user_

Wouldn't Keycloak's database be a better option than an in-memory Infinispan cache?

Comment: was thinking that Infinispan cache would be rather simpler, no?

Comment: With Infinispan, there is a synchronization complexity (delays/nodes in cluster with incorrect data/etc). With Keycloak DB, you have single source of truth, so any node in cluster, will return the same data.  If you still want to go with Infinispan, you can define a new cache in standalone.xml or reuse existing Keycloak cache like "keys" ( <local-cache name="keys">) or create it on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll have to look more into infinispan then because I thought it would handle all of those issues on its own. Btw. if this is not a good usecase for infinispan, what would one be? In any case, I'll indeed consider Keycloak's db for solving this problem, but I'll leave the question as a specific one for infinispan